# Android: Force different orientation for tablets programmatically

Tags: android, orientation, landscape-portrait

I want to force two different orientations in my app. Only portrait for smartphones and only landscape for tablets. Since I must define it in the manifest for each activity, I can't figure out how to it programmatically!

I tried with setRequestedOrientation(int requestedOrientation) in my activity onCreate but it doesn't really start with my requested orientation. There is some dalay before my request orientation is set.

Comment: "I want to force two different orientations in my app. Only portrait for smartphones and only landscape for tablets" -- why would a user want this?

Comment: because in a tablet my app is better suitable in landscape and in smatphones in portrait

Comment: But shouldn't the *user* get to decide what the *user* thinks is "better suitable"? It is the user's device, after all.

Comment: in general yes, but in this specific app I don't want let the user to decide

Comment: What about a 6 inch phone?

Answer (score 0):

Develop two different versions each forcing it's own orientation and targeting specific screen sizes and distribute.